# Buttons floating on page and serving as anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting floating buttons on my form to serve as anchors (the page is extensive), but only 1 button appears, but 3 buttons should be displayed.

The goal was when to slide the mouse scroll, to appear one button below the other with Unit 1, Unit 2 and Unit 3, respectively. And by clicking on them, go to their respective sessions. I'm not getting this with the 3 buttons, only with one and this is going to the top of the page.

Move the mouse and see the button (only one that appears)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                document.getElementById("navegacao1").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("navegacao1").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                document.getElementById("navegacao2").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("navegacao2").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                document.getElementById("navegacao3").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("navegacao3").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function anconrau1() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }

        function anconrau2() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }

        function anconrau3() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }

});
```

```css
.sessao-unidade {
    padding-top: 11px;
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
    border: 0px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sessao-titulos {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(27, 80, 124);
    background-color: #b4d5f1;
    border-color: #357ebd;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.sessao-titulos:hover, .sessao-titulos:active, .sessao-titulos:visited, .sessao-titulos:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.flutuante{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #e82222;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#navegacao1 {
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
  }

  #navegacao2 {
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 15px;
  }

  #navegacao3 {
    bottom: 60px;
    right: 15px;
  }
  
  #navegacao1:hover, #navegacao2:hover, #navegacao3:hover {
    background-color: #164b79;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="flutuante" onclick="anconrau1()" id="navegacao1" title="Ir ao topo">Unity 1</a>
<a class="flutuante" onclick="anconrau2()" id="navegacao2" title="Ir ao topo">Unity 2</a>
<a class="flutuante" onclick="anconrau3()" id="navegacao3" title="Ir ao topo">Unity 3</a>

<div id="div-unidades">

    <div id="unidade1">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span class="sessao-unidade">
                        Unity 1
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u1-conteudo-aulas" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u1-conteudo-aulas">
                        Classrooms
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u1-conteudo-aulas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-data-aula">Class number:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u1-data-aula" id="u1-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-data-aula">Classroom Date:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u1-data-aula" id="u1-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-tipo-aula">Classroom Type:</label>
                            <select name="" id="u1-tipo-aula" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Presential</option>
                                <option value="">Virtual</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <div class="u1-foruns-discussao">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u1-conteudo-foruns" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u1-conteudo-foruns">
                                Unit Discussion Forum
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse" id="u1-conteudo-foruns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-objetivo-forum">Forum Objective</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u1-objetivo-forum" id="u1-objetivo-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-ativacao-forum">Activation period for the unit:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u1-ativacao-forum" id="u1-ativacao-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-avaliacao-forum">Evaluation:</label>
                            <select name="u1-avaliacao-forum" id="u1-avaliacao-forum" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Not rated yet</option>
                                <option value="">With note</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-peso-forum">Weight (%):</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u1-peso-forum" id="u1-peso-forum" step="1" min="0" max="100">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="u1-demais-ferramentas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u1-conteudo-wiki" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u1-conteudo-wiki">
                            Other tools
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u1-conteudo-wiki">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-possui-wiki">Does the unit have a Wiki?</label>
                            <select name="" id="u1-possui-wiki" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Yes</option>
                                <option value="">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--UNIDADE 2 -->
    <div id="unidade2">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span class="sessao-unidade">
                        Unity 2
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u2-conteudo-aulas" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u2-conteudo-aulas">
                        Classrooms
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u2-conteudo-aulas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-data-aula">Class number:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u2-data-aula" id="u2-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-data-aula">Classroom Date:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u2-data-aula" id="u2-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-tipo-aula">Classroom Type:</label>
                            <select name="" id="u2-tipo-aula" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Presential</option>
                                <option value="">Virtual</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- FORUNS DE DISCUSSÃO DA UNIDADE -->

            <div class="u2-foruns-discussao">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u2-conteudo-foruns" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u2-conteudo-foruns">
                                Unit Discussion Forum
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse" id="u2-conteudo-foruns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-objetivo-forum">Forum Objective</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u2-objetivo-forum" id="u2-objetivo-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-ativacao-forum">Activation period for the unit:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u2-ativacao-forum" id="u2-ativacao-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-avaliacao-forum">Evaluation:</label>
                            <select name="u2-avaliacao-forum" id="u2-avaliacao-forum" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Not rated yet</option>
                                <option value="">With note</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-peso-forum">Weight (%):</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u2-peso-forum" id="u2-peso-forum" step="1" min="0" max="100">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Other tools -->

            <div class="u2-demais-ferramentas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u2-conteudo-wiki" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u2-conteudo-wiki">
                            Other tools
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u2-conteudo-wiki">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-possui-wiki">Does the unit have a Wiki?</label>
                            <select name="" id="u2-possui-wiki" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Yes</option>
                                <option value="">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--UNIDADE 3 -->
    <div id="unidade3">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span class="sessao-unidade">
                    Unity 3
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u3-conteudo-aulas" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u3-conteudo-aulas">
                    Classrooms
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="u3-conteudo-aulas">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-data-aula">Class number:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u3-data-aula" id="u3-data-aula">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-data-aula">Classroom Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u3-data-aula" id="u3-data-aula">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-tipo-aula">Classroom Type:</label>
                        <select name="" id="u3-tipo-aula" class="form-control">
                            <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                            <option value="">Presential</option>
                            <option value="">Virtual</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- FORUNS DE DISCUSSÃO DA UNIDADE -->

        <div class="u3-foruns-discussao">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u3-conteudo-foruns" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u3-conteudo-foruns">
                            Unit Discussion Forum
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u3-conteudo-foruns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-objetivo-forum">Forum Objective</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u3-objetivo-forum" id="u3-objetivo-forum">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-ativacao-forum">Activation period for the unit:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u3-ativacao-forum" id="u3-ativacao-forum">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-avaliacao-forum">Evaluation:</label>
                        <select name="u3-avaliacao-forum" id="u3-avaliacao-forum" class="form-control">
                            <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                            <option value="">Not rated yet</option>
                            <option value="">With note</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-peso-forum">Weight (%):</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u3-peso-forum" id="u3-peso-forum" step="1" min="0" max="100">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="u3-demais-ferramentas">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u3-conteudo-wiki" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u3-conteudo-wiki">
                        Other tools
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="u3-conteudo-wiki">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-possui-wiki">Does the unit have a Wiki?</label>
                        <select name="" id="u3-possui-wiki" class="form-control">
                            <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                            <option value="">Yes</option>
                            <option value="">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('#navegacao1,#navegacao2,#navegacao3').click(function(){` rather than using separate functions

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                document.getElementById("navegacao1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("navegacao2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("navegacao3").style.display = "none";
                     
 } else if ((document.body.scrollTop > 20 && document.body.scrollTop > 20 )||  (document.body.scrollTop < 30 && document.body.scrollTop < 30)) {
            document.getElementById("navegacao2").style.display = "block";
                           document.getElementById("navegacao1").style.display = "none";
                           document.getElementById("navegacao3").style.display = "none";
       }
            else if ((document.body.scrollTop < 30 && document.body.scrollTop > 30 )||  (document.body.scrollTop <50 && document.body.scrollTop <50)) {
                document.getElementById("navegacao3").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("navegacao1").style.display = "none";          document.getElementById("navegacao2").style.display = "none";
                }
                
            
        }

        

$(function(){
        $('#navegacao1,#navegacao2,#navegacao3').click(function(){
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        });
       
    });

});
```

```css
.sessao-unidade {
    padding-top: 11px;
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
    border: 0px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sessao-titulos {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(27, 80, 124);
    background-color: #b4d5f1;
    border-color: #357ebd;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.sessao-titulos:hover, .sessao-titulos:active, .sessao-titulos:visited, .sessao-titulos:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.flutuante{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #e82222;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#navegacao1 {
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
  }

  #navegacao2 {
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 15px;
  }

  #navegacao3 {
    bottom: 60px;
    right: 15px;
  }
  
  #navegacao1:hover, #navegacao2:hover, #navegacao3:hover {
    background-color: #164b79;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="flutuante"  id="navegacao1" title="Ir ao topo">Unity 1</a>
<a class="flutuante"  id="navegacao2" title="Ir ao topo">Unity 2</a>
<a class="flutuante"  id="navegacao3" title="Ir ao topo">Unity 3</a>

<div id="div-unidades" style="height:1000px">

    <div id="unidade1">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span class="sessao-unidade">
                        Unity 1
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u1-conteudo-aulas" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u1-conteudo-aulas">
                        Classrooms
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u1-conteudo-aulas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-data-aula">Class number:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u1-data-aula" id="u1-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-data-aula">Classroom Date:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u1-data-aula" id="u1-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-tipo-aula">Classroom Type:</label>
                            <select name="" id="u1-tipo-aula" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Presential</option>
                                <option value="">Virtual</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <div class="u1-foruns-discussao">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u1-conteudo-foruns" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u1-conteudo-foruns">
                                Unit Discussion Forum
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse" id="u1-conteudo-foruns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-objetivo-forum">Forum Objective</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u1-objetivo-forum" id="u1-objetivo-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-ativacao-forum">Activation period for the unit:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u1-ativacao-forum" id="u1-ativacao-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-avaliacao-forum">Evaluation:</label>
                            <select name="u1-avaliacao-forum" id="u1-avaliacao-forum" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Not rated yet</option>
                                <option value="">With note</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-peso-forum">Weight (%):</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u1-peso-forum" id="u1-peso-forum" step="1" min="0" max="100">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="u1-demais-ferramentas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u1-conteudo-wiki" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u1-conteudo-wiki">
                            Other tools
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u1-conteudo-wiki">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u1-possui-wiki">Does the unit have a Wiki?</label>
                            <select name="" id="u1-possui-wiki" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Yes</option>
                                <option value="">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--UNIDADE 2 -->
    <div id="unidade2">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span class="sessao-unidade">
                        Unity 2
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u2-conteudo-aulas" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u2-conteudo-aulas">
                        Classrooms
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u2-conteudo-aulas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-data-aula">Class number:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u2-data-aula" id="u2-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-data-aula">Classroom Date:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u2-data-aula" id="u2-data-aula">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-tipo-aula">Classroom Type:</label>
                            <select name="" id="u2-tipo-aula" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Presential</option>
                                <option value="">Virtual</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- FORUNS DE DISCUSSÃO DA UNIDADE -->

            <div class="u2-foruns-discussao">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u2-conteudo-foruns" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u2-conteudo-foruns">
                                Unit Discussion Forum
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse" id="u2-conteudo-foruns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-objetivo-forum">Forum Objective</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u2-objetivo-forum" id="u2-objetivo-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-ativacao-forum">Activation period for the unit:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u2-ativacao-forum" id="u2-ativacao-forum">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-avaliacao-forum">Evaluation:</label>
                            <select name="u2-avaliacao-forum" id="u2-avaliacao-forum" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Not rated yet</option>
                                <option value="">With note</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-peso-forum">Weight (%):</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u2-peso-forum" id="u2-peso-forum" step="1" min="0" max="100">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Other tools -->

            <div class="u2-demais-ferramentas">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u2-conteudo-wiki" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u2-conteudo-wiki">
                            Other tools
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u2-conteudo-wiki">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="u2-possui-wiki">Does the unit have a Wiki?</label>
                            <select name="" id="u2-possui-wiki" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                                <option value="">Yes</option>
                                <option value="">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--UNIDADE 3 -->
    <div id="unidade3">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span class="sessao-unidade">
                    Unity 3
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u3-conteudo-aulas" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u3-conteudo-aulas">
                    Classrooms
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="u3-conteudo-aulas">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-data-aula">Class number:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u3-data-aula" id="u3-data-aula">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-data-aula">Classroom Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u3-data-aula" id="u3-data-aula">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-tipo-aula">Classroom Type:</label>
                        <select name="" id="u3-tipo-aula" class="form-control">
                            <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                            <option value="">Presential</option>
                            <option value="">Virtual</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- FORUNS DE DISCUSSÃO DA UNIDADE -->

        <div class="u3-foruns-discussao">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u3-conteudo-foruns" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u3-conteudo-foruns">
                            Unit Discussion Forum
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="u3-conteudo-foruns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-objetivo-forum">Forum Objective</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u3-objetivo-forum" id="u3-objetivo-forum">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-ativacao-forum">Activation period for the unit:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="u3-ativacao-forum" id="u3-ativacao-forum">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-avaliacao-forum">Evaluation:</label>
                        <select name="u3-avaliacao-forum" id="u3-avaliacao-forum" class="form-control">
                            <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                            <option value="">Not rated yet</option>
                            <option value="">With note</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-peso-forum">Weight (%):</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="u3-peso-forum" id="u3-peso-forum" step="1" min="0" max="100">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="u3-demais-ferramentas">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <a class="sessao-titulos" data-toggle="collapse" href="#u3-conteudo-wiki" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="u3-conteudo-wiki">
                        Other tools
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="u3-conteudo-wiki">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="u3-possui-wiki">Does the unit have a Wiki?</label>
                        <select name="" id="u3-possui-wiki" class="form-control">
                            <option hidden="true">Select item</option>
                            <option value="">Yes</option>
                            <option value="">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue of button overlapping I can solve in CSS. But just to point out, they are not going as an anchor. When you press the button, you are going to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are overriding the funcion `scrollfunction` three times, so the only one which is used is the last defined.

Also you should check the scrollTop value depending on each element as you are comparing for all three functions if the scrollTop value is greater than 20.

Comment: Gave more or less right. The problem now is that the button is not redirecting to the session, it's just going to the top of the page.